# Invoice for purchases made on App Store

Tags: ios-appstore, mac-appstore

Does Apple provide invoice for purchases made on the App Store? I want for one of my past purchases.

I am unable to find the invoice email from Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to invoice for any past purchases made on iOS or Mac App Store from Apple's [Report a Problem](https://reportaproblem.apple.com) website.

Open the website and login with the Apple ID that was used to make the purchase.

Report a Problem website also lets you fetch invoice for any services from Apple you are subscribed to.

Answer (score 1):

To see your past App Store purchases, follow [these steps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204088):

### On a Mac

1. Open the Music app or iTunes. From the menu bar at the top of the screen, choose Account, then click View My Account.
2. On the Account Information page, scroll down to Purchase History. Next to Most Recent Purchase, click See All.

[image]

3. Find the item. It might take a moment for your Purchase History to appear. If you want to see purchases that you made more than 90 days prior, click Last 90 Days, then select a date range.

### On an iOS/iPadOS device

See your purchase history on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch

1. Open the Settings app.
2. Tap your name, then tap Media & Purchases. You might be asked to sign in.
3. Tap Purchase History.

[image]

4. Your purchase history appears. If you want to see purchases that you made more than 90 days prior, tap Last 90 Days, then select a different date range.

Answer (score 1):

These work fine (App Store Account view) except they aren't an actual receipt for tax purposes.  It doesn't break down the sales tax or anything.  I need to see GST and PST separately.

[image]

I find Apple sends proper receipts way late, just long enough to think it's never going to show up.  Strange that you can't find a proper receipt on the website or the App store.

EDIT:  I see the "Report A Problem" link actually lets you click "view receipt" and there's a proper receipt with all the info you need for tax purposes.  Great!  Thanks for that link [Nimesh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/279727/nimesh-neema)!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/324981)

Comment: I don't understand.  I noted an significant difference in the receipts available from these two sources.  As I need these for tax purposes, and others probably do also, it seems important to point out.  But I did just now upvote the helpful comment, as you suggested.